# Statistics Set Theory

Tags: probability, statistics

Prove or disprove the following statement:

> If $p(a)= p(b)= q$ then $p\left(a \cap b\right) ≤ q^2$

We know nothing know about sets $a$ and $b$. They may or may not be disjoint.

Answer (score 5):

False. Let $a = b = $ "my coin comes up  heads when I toss it."  Then $P(a) = P(b)= 1/2$, and $P(a \cap b) = 1/2 > 1/4$.

Let's look at the probability space:

```
H     T
```

The associated probability masses are each 1/2, because we'll assume it's a fair coin.

The event $a$ consists of the single outcome $H$, i.e., $a = \{ H \}$. The probability of $a$ is the sum of the probabilities of the outcomes in $a$, which is $1/2$.

Since $b$ is the same as $a$, the probability of the event $b$ is also $1/2$.

The event $a \cap b$ is just 
$$
a \cap b = \{ H \} \cap \{ H \}= \{ H \}.
$$
which is again $a$. So the probability is the same as that of $a$, namely $1/2$.

Comment: your assumption ?

Comment: how come its gives 1/2

Comment: See additional information in answer.

Comment: This is not true  P(a∩b) ={H}∩{H}={H}. Be course, event "a"  and "b " are two different events having same probability. so it's not {H}∩{H}
your explanation is wrong..


Can any body prove this ??

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are not two different events; they are the same event, with two different names. The experiment is "you flip the coin ONCE, and it either comes up heads or tails." And $a$ is the event "it comes up heads," and $b$ is the *same* event. (You can tell: I wrote, as the first line, let $a = b = \ldots$"; that pretty much means that $a$ and $b$ are the same event!) [Also notice that as of now, at least 5 other people think I've given a correct answer...you might want to read what I wrote very carefully to be certain you understand it. ]